# Django error 404 2458 when requesting objects by id

Tags: python, django

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsJRXS_vrw0) video trying to learn Django. I have completed [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) tutorial and I had the same problem even when I followed the code to a T.

I am trying to get information about a model object displayed on the web-page when entering the id of the object directly in the url like  http://localhost:8000/app/item/1/  or http://localhost:8000/app/item/2/ as the video shows (7:30 into the video). But when I try, I get this error:

[image]

---

Original code from video:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Book 


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, world!')

def book_by_id(request, book_id):
    book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
    return HttpResponse(f"Book: {book.title}, published on {book.pub_date}")
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)  
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.utils import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('book/<int:book_id>', views.book_by_id, name='book_by_id'),
]
```

---

My code:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Item


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, world!')

def item_by_id(request, item_id):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=item_id)
    return HttpResponse(f"Item: {item.title}, published on {item.datetime_found}")
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # Short description of the item
    datetime_found = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)  # Date and time of when the item was found
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('item/<int:item_id>', views.item_by_id, name='item_by_id'),
]
```

Project-level urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

---

What am I not getting right about the GET-request? I feel like the changes I've made are minimal. And I have migrated everything correctly. (I think)

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash from your URL (or the other way around, add the trailing slash to your `path()` invocation).

Comment: I tried both yet I still get the same error-page

Comment: Do you have a project level `urls.py` or is that itself your project level urls? If that is so then where do you expect that `app` to come from in your urls (I don't see that in your pattern)?

Comment: Yes, I have a project level urls.py. I have edited my question to include it

Comment: Well, again where do you expect `app` to come from? The tutorial you speak of likely had something like `path('app/', include('theirapp.urls')),`. You likely want to write the url as `http://localhost:8000/item/1/` in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('app/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

or you can remove 'app' from your url and make it look like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/1

Comment: Any reason you deleted your other answer? You do know that you can edit right? There is an edit button just below the post body at the left of your user card.

Comment: Yeah I know, it just didn't strike my mind.

Answer (score 1):

look at url pattern of yours and the original.

`path('item/<int:item_id>', views.item_by_id, name='item_by_id'),`

is yours

`path('book/<int:book_id>', views.book_by_id, name='book_by_id'),`
is the original

Comment: yes, I made an  item_by_id-function instead of the original book_by_id-function in views.py. I am not sure I understand your answer...